# What IP address would I check if my email is blacklisted?

Tags: email, dns, blacklist, dig

I have a server hosting a website with an ISP. That server's IP address is X. I can also see MX records for my domain, they resolve to the IP address Y.

People have been telling me "your email is ending up in my spam folder", so I think some IP address ended up on a blacklist somewhere.

Do I check the IP address of my server? The IP address of the MX records of my domain? Or some possibly third IP address, and if so, how do I determine that third IP address?

Comment: Look yourself up in Spamhaus

Comment: What exactly am I looking up though? The domain names used in my email addresses, the mx records, or possibly something else? Are mx records used for outbound email? Is my web server used for outbound email? Seems like not in both cases, so how would i determine the unknown third ip address?

Comment: Look up the domain names of the email landing in peoples' spam folders to see if the name exist in Spam Haus.

Comment: Use the email header of the Received Emails to help you and to see what the headers say.

Comment: My guess is you aren't implementing DMARC, so mail clients can't tell that the webhosts email server is allowed to send email on behalf of your domain. blocklists are usually applied at the mailserver, and block mail from being received at all, not sticking it in the spam bin. implementing DMARC/DKIM/SFP is technology specific so you;ll have to look it up for your own system, but it will involve you publishing dns records (cnames or txt recs) in your domains authoritative dns server/zone pointing to the mailserver.